# Not able to connect to Azure SQL database from Microsoft SQL Server Management Tool

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am able to connect to Azure SQL Server from liquibase using jtds drivers and run the query.

When I am trying to connect from SQL Server Management Studio, using the same credentials:

- Server Type: Database Engine
- Server Name: myserver.database.windows.net,1433
- Authentication: SQL Server authentication
- Login: username (username and password are provided appropriately)
- Password: password

I get the error as shown below.

Note: I have changed the server name as it is confidential.

> Cannot connect to myserver.database.windows.net,1433.
>
> Login failed for user 'username'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> Server Name: myserver.database.windows.net,1433
> Error Number: 18456
> Severity: 14
> State: 1
> Line Number: 65536
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

Comment: Perhaps you need to select options and login to a specific database?

Answer (score 0):

The server name should be something like this **`servername.database.windows.net`**

You can get the server name from portal from Overview or from Azure SQL database connection string.

[image]

In **SSMS**, give the copied server name from the portal as shown in screenshot.

> Do not give port number in the server name while connecting from SSMS.

[image]

Refer this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-ssms#get-server-connection-information) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have found Error 18456 with State 1 only during Microsoft Azure outages. To make sure visit [@AzureSupport](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) on Twitter or visit [Azure Status](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status). Sometimes Azure Support and Azure Status do not show any issues because issues may not be affecting a good number of customers, but you can still find out what is happening by going to Help + Support, choose Service Health, then examine "Health History" and "Resource Health" as shown on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resource-health-exposes-historical-health/) article.

Another possible cause of this error is the status of your Azure Subscription. Maybe your subscription requires your attention.